# Hover over an image so that another hover image can perform an animate

Tags: javascript

So, I have this project to do for school and and partially got my answer from [Reveal image underneath a mask css/javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772063/reveal-image-underneath-a-mask-css-javascript) which is awesome.

The thing is, I do not want the color to move when I point my mouse over to the glass.  Instead, what if I have 5 small thumbnails of different colors (listing on the side of the glass), which when I point to each of them, that would be the color moving in the glass. Is that possible? Would someone help me please.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What glass are you talking about?  What does this look like?  We want to help, but you have to give us enough details that we are able to help.

Comment: He means the glass here http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/SptRr/7/

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to change the color of the div that is the water "animation". Which you can easily do with `$("div").css("background-color", color);` that is attached to events on some display objects (5 small thumbnails in your case).

Here is a small example @ JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MartinTale/Mz6VH/1/

Answer (score 0):

As Martin said, you can simply change the background color based upon what you are hovering. However this can be slightly problematic if you then hover over a different color (the color will then switch before finishing the animation).

If you have some markup like this:

```
<img src='http://www.videsignz.com/testing/images/water-front2.png' />
  <div id="blue-fill"></div>
  <div id="red-fill"></div>
  <div id="green-fill"></div>

<div class="thumbnails">
  <div id="blue"></div>
  <div id="red"></div>
  <div id="green"></div>
</div>
```

And you can use this line of jQuery in your function to get the corresponding element

```
      var theFill = "#" + $(this).attr("id") + "-fill";
```

This is basically grabbing the id of the current hovered element and concatenating on the format of your fill selector.

You can then grab select your fill using

```
$(theFill)
```

and animate from there. I made a codepen example with class attributes and the required css for styling: http://codepen.io/prythm/pen/Lwoyd

Comment: I have a few more other questions, would you mind emailing me at love2le@yahoo.com ???

Comment: If it's related to the question please post them here? Also could you please accept my answer if it has worked?

Comment: Thank you again. My next step beyond this is, what if I have have a picture of flying balloons (which is located at different places on an image) and have few thumbnails of patterns on the side instead of color values.  So, how can I mouse over one of the pattern and the whole balloons turned into that pattern and when I move my mouse over the next pattern, the same thing happen just like how you do the glass.  The only different is now I have different spaces to fill in and the "fill in" is actually patterns and not color values.

Comment: So, I've played around and got to this.  I created an image of balloons with no fill in them (PNG file). Then I created another image with filled pattern (JPEG file).  I then created the animate function where when the mouse move over the empty balloons, the filled balloons image will animate underneath that empty image, thus my empty balloons now is filled with the pattern.  The illusion I tried to make.

Comment: Now, I need help in setting up 4 thumbnails of different patterns on the side (2 on top row, and 2 on the next row on the side of the empty balloons).  When I move the mouse over in a particular pattern, the "illusion" of that pattern will filled the empty balloons (and of course, that means I have 4 different JPEG images of the filled balloons w/ 4 different patterns).  These images will animate underneath the empty balloons on mouse over.  Please help me.  I'm stuck.  I tried various way, but somehow it didn't work.  Thank you so much!