# Making a "dynamic" div responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Continuing off [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772063/reveal-image-underneath-a-mask-css-javascript), I'm trying to emulate the same animation all while resizing the window.

So far, I've added the ".img-responsive" class **(found in bootstrap.css)** to the image, but unfortunately, the div's dimensions don't adjust accordingly.

What should I do?

HTML:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src='http://www.videsignz.com/testing/images/water-front2.png' />
<div></div>
```

JS:

```
function animateit(){

    $('div').animate({'height' : '350px', 'top' : 0 }, 2000, function() {
        $('div').animate({'height' : 0, 'top' : '350px' }, 2000, animateit);
    });

}

animateit();
```

CSS:

```
.img-responsive {
    display: block;
    width: 100% \9;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

img {
    position:absolute; 
    left:0px; 
    top:0px; 
    z-index:5;
}

div {
    position:absolute; 
    left:0px; 
    top:350px; 
    background-color:#67d9ff; 
    height:0px; 
    display:block; 
    width:350px;
}
```

Comment: what is the css for `.img-responsive`?

Comment: My bad, forget to mention I was using Bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is not the cleanest way to do this but it is a solution. You can wrap the elements in a container set to `position:relative` (to contain them) and `overflow:hidden` (that way the excess blue "water" will not be visible) and then add a duplicate image inside that wrapper set to `opacity:0`. The purpose of the second image is to keep the height and width of the container from collapsing seeing how the other two elements are position `absolute` and do not register a `width` or `height`:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="hidden" src='http://www.videsignz.com/testing/images/water-front2.png' />
  <img class="glass img-responsive" src='http://www.videsignz.com/testing/images/water-front2.png' />
  <div class="water"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  height:auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 350px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  width: 100% \9;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.glass {
  position:absolute; 
  left:0px; 
  top:0px; 
  z-index:5;
}

.hidden{
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.water {
  position:absolute; 
  left:0px; 
  right: 0;
  top:350px; 
  background-color:#67d9ff; 
  height:0px; 
  display:block; 
}
```

**JS**

```
function animateit(){

  $('.wrapper .water').animate({'height' : '350px', 'top' : 0 }, 2000, function() {
    $('.wrapper .water').animate({'height' : 0, 'top' : '350px' }, 2000, animateit);
  });

}

animateit();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rt7hpfz9/1/)

The issue was bootstrap has a class called `.hidden` (which I just happened to name mine) which set the image to `display: none` thus was not registering the height. I changed the name of my class:

[**WORKING BOOTPLY**](http://www.bootply.com/bQURuGbeH8)

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason I can't get it to work in [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/1A4f1mIqAv).

Comment: (Unless I reveal overflow and defeat the purpose.)

Comment: Thanks so much. Now it's just a matter of fitting in with what I already have. Sweet.

Comment: As an afterthought, is there also any way to center this? Because I'm really having trouble with it.